Make a beltless clip-on bear spray holster
I want a bear spray holster that clips onto pants. Reason: I don't wear a belt, I wear suspenders under other clothing.

https://www.amazon.com/Guard-Alaska-Pepper-Defense-Holster/dp/B01HC2FXAK?th=1
I haven't found a holster like that for sale in Canada. I've googled it and contacted several stores and manufacturers, with no luck.
I'm aware of other holster styles, such as the waistband and chest styles, but I'm specifically looking for a clip-on holster. It's a matter of personal preference: I don't want it strapped to me or in my pocket; I want a holster that easily clips to the pocket of my pants.
As a temporary solution, I've used a carabiner to attach the spray to a belt loop. But it's too awkward to unclip, especially if under duress. And the spray moves around too much, hitting things while working, risking damage to the spray.
Question:
How can I make a holster that has a spring-loaded clip at home?
I've wondered why such holsters aren't widely available. Maybe it's because the holster can fall off when hiking, and so the spray would get lost. That's less of an issue for me because I'm working at a single location building a cabin. So it would be less likely for me to lose it if it became dislodged.

That clip really doesn't look like something I'd want on a waistband. What do you plan to clip it to?

Get holster and clip separately?

@ChrisH [typos corrected] If the clip is sharp, I could clip it into the small front pocket in my jeans. hockerty.com/en-ca/blog/small-pocket-jeans.

I got no sense of scale, but I wonder if a flashlight holder would work

Are you up to adding a specific pocket to your pants sized for this spray?   Clearly would require some sewing.

@JourneymanGeek Or a waterbottle holder. Although those might not clip on.

@Criggie Interesting idea, but I think I'd like the solution for multiple pairs of pants.

doesn't look super complicated. Do you know how to sew?

You could look into Kydex, it is what is used to make custom and DIY gun holsters, you usually need a heat press, but may be able to get away without one and just use a heat gun seeing as you would just be needing a cylinder shape. then drill and add clip on it.

@User1974, please accept the answer that works for you, accepting your own answer is okay on this site.

One option is to "get a holster and a clip separately", as suggested by @TomasBy.

Clip: HolsterSmith Universal Metal Belt Clip for Holster Making, Knife Sheaths, Cell Phone Cases

Holster: Kodiak Singletrack 225g Bear Spray Holster

Attach the clip to the plastic holster using small bolts, lock washers, and nuts from Home Depot. Drill holes in the plastic for the bolts. It's not visible in the next photo, but the top hole under the clip has a bolt, too.


For the nuts/bolts at the bottom, the opening in the plastic container was too narrow to fit my hand or regular needle nose pliers. I used extra long and narrow needle nose pliers to hold the nut and place the lock washer.


The bear spray and holster fit into a travel container if I remove the foam from the container. So that's handy; no need to store the holster separately.

Bear spray in vehicle - risk of leak causing accident

Regarding my comment in the question:

I've wondered why such holsters aren't widely available. Maybe it's because the holster can fall off when hiking, and so the spray would get lost.

That turns out not to be an issue because the clip has a catch (a small sharp piece) that digs into the clothing, making it difficult to remove the clip/holster without intentionally bending the clip away from the fabric. The clip is quite strong.

I thought I would expand on my suggestion for Kydex a bit. Yes you could sew one as well, but this design will basically last forever with minimal maintenance.
Note that there are some tools and materials that would need to be purchased for this, but once you have them you could make other holsters as well.
Those include the sheet(s) of Kydex, the belt clip, small nuts and bolts, a heat gun, and rubber o-rings etc.

Measure the circumference of the bearspray can. Then cut your sheet of Kydex to roughly that width plus a half inch or so on each end. More is better here as you can cut off whatever extra there is after making the bolt holes.

Find a cylinder to use as a mold that is the same circumference of your bearspray, then find/make a thin but sturdy rectangle the size of your belt clip
to create a flat portion to install the belt clip to. Glue the rectangle to the cylinder.

Using a heat gun, heat the kydex and wrap it around the mold making sure to leave the extra tabs to bolt it together. (DO NOT USE THE BEARSPRAY AS A CYLINDER AND HIT IT WITH A HEAT GUN)

Once the Kydex has cooled, drill 3 holes in the tab where you would like your bolts to be. Source rubber O-rings to allow adjusting the retention on the can and place them between the sheets and around the bolts.

Using rivets, or something flat on the inside, install your belt clip.

Heat the extra tab near the joint and fold it inward to create a bottom tab for the can to sit on.

Quick draw and spray bears in the face.


Yes, I numbered the image wrong.

